# ios youtube video keeps on playing in background

Tags: ios, webview, youtube, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing YouTube videos in a separate `viewController` (say `videoViewController`) in my iPad app, i have a home view controller having a button to load `videoViewController`.

Every thing works fine video is playing when i click on play icon. I am using this code

```
[_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%@", @"eOG90Q8EfRo"]]]];
```

Now this `videoViewController` have a back button on the top using below code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When I click it, the home `viewController` is displayed but the video keeps on playing. Even when I again go to `videoViewController` it is still playing until I select a new video to play.

I tried calling `viewDidUnload` before piping the view controller and tried below code

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [_webview stopLoading];
    _webview.delegate = nil;
    [self setWebview:nil];
}
```

However nothing happens, I want that video to stop playing when I press the back button.

I guess the video is playing in the `MPMoviePlayerController` provided by the iOS is there any way so that I can get a reference to it to make the video stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution to my problem.

Finally i got it working :

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [_webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use load blank page when you want to back to main controller.

```
 [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing for iOS 6?

If you are, then viewDidUnload is deprecated. Try it with viewDidDisappear.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear {
    [_webview stopLoading];
    _webview.delegate = nil;
    [self setWebview:nil];
}
```

Comment: yes i know that i tried calling -viewDidUnload before [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; but nothing happens